# Can't double click to run Kivy python script

Tags: python, kivy

I can run the script just fine using PyCharm or command line, and there's no issue with file associations because I can run other Python 3 scripts by double clicking. When I try to run by double clicking, nothing happens. The Kivy log shows several lines like this:

```
[WARNING] stderr: --- Logging error ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out adding this to the top of the script fixes it if you don't need the console logging. It seems to crash if it has nowhere to put logs, which is what happened when I tried to run it without a console.

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG'] = '1'
```